# connect to remote wpengine mysql service with php/pdo

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Following the instructions here:

https://wpengine.com/support/setting-remote-database-access/

I'm able to connect to mysql from my command line with:

mysql -uuser -ppassword -h instance.sftp.wpengine.com -P13306 -D database --default-auth=mysql_native_password

But when I try the same parameters through php/pdo:

`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$db.';default-auth=mysql_native_password', $user, $pass);`

I get this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 0):

You need to add options and specify the .pem key.

You can download the pem key from the instructions in the question:

https://wpengine.com/support/setting-remote-database-access/ - save wpengine_root_ca.pem to the same directory as your script.

```
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $db = '';
    $port = '13306';
    $host = 'instance.sftp.wpengine.com';  //put your account name instead of 'instance' here
    $options = ['default-auth'=>'mysql_native_password',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=>__DIR__.'/wpengine_root_ca.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false];
    
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$db.';default-auth=mysql_native_password', $user, $pass, $options);
```

You should read over the directions carefully and also make sure that WP Engine has whitelisted your ip address.